# Can similar_text() function be used to match the passwords ? If so, then How?

Tags: php, backend

I know javascript can do it for me, but as a beginner in PHP, I am curious about knowing this.

Comment: *"Can similar_text() function be used to match the passwords ? If so, then How?"* - Did you try it? Where's your code?

Comment: In what context "match password"? in the user "changing their password" context, PHP is a server side language so this would be really inappropriate to use in that way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It must be better to compare directly with == :

```
<?php

$storedpassword  = md5('mypasswd');

if (md5($_POST['password']) == $storedpassword) {
    echo 'ok';
} else {
    echo 'not ok';
}
```

Comment: Do not use md5 with passwords. it is **VERY** weak

Answer (score 1):

Yes, You can use `similar_text()` of PHP to compare the passwords. 
This function can handle even case sensitive.

For example -

```
<?php
$item1 = "Hello";
$item2 = "Hello";

echo similar_text($item1,$item2,$percent);
echo $percent; // 100
?>
```

In the above code, you will get the percent as 100%.So you can give a condition as if the result is 100 then password comparison is success.

Comment: with the completion that: `if ($percent == 100){ //they match }` then this should be marked as the solution to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible you hash both passwords and then check if you have a 100% match:

```
<?php

$hash1 = hash('sha512', 'hello world');
$hash2 = hash('sha512', 'hello world');

similar_text($hash1, $hash2, $percent); 

if($percent == 100){
    echo 'same';
} else {
    echo 'different';
}
```

Comment: out of curiosity, why go through the hash process rather than just compare the strings directly?

Comment: Because you don't store passwords as plain text, I'm guessing he's using some sort of hashing in his database for passwords.

Comment: ah ok, I was just seeing this answer in the context of the `similar_text` rather than the fact they're passwords.